# Block a specific IP address from accessing portions of your website

Tags: security, .htaccess, crm, blocking

I'm hosting my site on Cent OS 6.3 bundled with Apache webserver.

I have my website and my CRM hosted on the same server. How do I block all other IP's and restrict the access to a specific IP.

EX:
https://www.website.com is my website and I want this to be available to all but

https://www.website.com/crm should be restricted to all and should be allowed on a particular IP only

Please help me find a solution for this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether or not your web host allows overriding access rules in `.htaccess`. 
Try creating the following file `.htaccess` in the directory which corresponds to `/crm' resource on your site (if the file already exists, just add these directives to it):

```
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all 
    Allow from <allowed-ip-1>
    Allow from <allowed-ip-2>
    ....
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html for detailed syntax of `Allow` and `Deny` rules.

This may or may not work depending on your hosting provide policies. Not all of them permit this.
If that doesn't work and your hosting prover does not cooperate, the problem is much more complicated - in that case you need the application managing `/crm` resource to handle access restrictions.

Comment: It did not help! i checked with my Hosting provider, they do not have any restrictions!